# Edit array of axis output from pandas plot method

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting from a pandas dataframe with subplots and as a result I get a np.array with a number of axis.

```
array([<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at blablabla>,
       <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at blablabla>,
       <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at blablabla>])
```

I want to grab this output to edit the title, x label and save it as pdf. If it was only one axis I would first grab the output of the `.plot` in a variable, say `ax` and then set the title and get the figure with `fig = ax.get_figure()` to save it the way I want. How can I do the same here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `ax =` infront of df.plot to get a list of axes.  Then you can use list slicing to access each axes object and set_title, etc.. as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

ax = df.plot(subplots=True)
ax[0].set_title('Series A')
ax[1].set_title('Series B')
ax[2].set_title('Series C')
ax[3].set_title('Series D')
fig = ax[0].get_figure()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]